# Video player with custom menu?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add a custom menu onto a html based video player - In a similar fashion to the "Like, Edit, Share" menu that comes up on the right of any vimeo content.

Is the a jquery plugin I need to be using? or a HTML 5 approach? Some guidance on this would be appreciated.

EDIT : I should also add here, that the menu would preferably appear on hover... I am interested in knowing how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS to position the menu relative to the HTML video element and hide it and then use :hover (CSS) or .onMouseOver (jQuery) to make the menu visible.

Comment: Thanks... I feel stupid for asking now, as I had been thinking this might be the approach but thought there might be a given control... :)